# Actionscript-3 looping issue--Adobe Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flash, animation, actionscript

My employer decided they wanted me to start doing animation with Adobe's new "Animate CC" application.  My issue is that I don't know how to **loop** my animation outside of the Adobe Animate environment.  I am new to Adobe Animate CC and ActionScript, unfortunately, so I will probably need a relatively basic answer to understand why my solution isn't working.  From what I can tell, my ActionScript code is being ignored by the IDE completely.

In the IDE and in the browser test command, the animation plays beyond frame 100, to the end, and then flashes a frame of white before repeating.  I need it to loop without this white frame interrupting the screen, whether that be through a loop or some other means that I'm just not aware of.

For context: my project has about 100 layers of content and I'm unfamiliar with how this program works.  I've thoroughly searched the web for tutorials on how to do what I need to do, but I've come up empty handed.

I have an actions layer among my motion tweens and other layers
https://gyazo.com/6e0b8502d98b6c9903bb96ac3a939bae

I've been trying to use gotoAndPlay(0) at frame 100 to start the animation over from the beginning.
https://gyazo.com/704ee7158bae6dfd149b6283cfa33451

Basically, how do I use Action-Script in Adobe Animate CC in order to infinitely loop my animation until closed?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You need to show your progress, otherwise people will say rtfm... I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Fair enough.  I added some screenshots of my work to show more detail of what I've done.

Comment: So is there an issue with doing `gotoAndPlay(0)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  I have the action at the 100th frame and the animation plays past my action code to the end.  When it gets to the end, it briefly freezes and flashes a frame of all white before playing again.  I would be fine without having the loop if it didn't freeze before repeating even, but...  Also, it does this in both the IDE and when using the test command for a browser.

Comment: Do you have any other actions?  `gotoAndPlay(1)` should take you back to the start of the animation.   Though if you lots of complex vector content it could be a performance issue.

Comment: As I believe @BadFeelingAboutThis is on to something in his comment regarding the complexity being an issue, my suggestion is to export your animation as a .mov file (or something like that) and then make a new .fla that just plays that .mov file.  Would that be an option for you?  Look into `FLVPlayerComponent` which is an extension of the `Sprite` object.

Comment: I have no other actions in my animation other than the goto. I will try your suggestion with converting the file, @NealDavis, and see what that does.  So far I've tried changing the key frame at which it restarts, doing a `gotoAndStop(101)` with my `gotoAndPlay(0)`, among a few other things that I'll remember as the morning progresses.

Comment: And you're sure that the gotoAndPlay is on the timeline that you want to loop? not a sub/child timeline?

Comment: I believe so simply because I've not created any other timeline than the one that I'm working with currently.  My next thought is if I need my action across every layer in order for it to loop the way I want or if the single layer with my actions should work (theoretically) as is.

Comment: Is there perhaps another way to include ActionScript in my animation aside from putting it in a layer on the timeline?  Or maybe a property built into Adobe Animate that tells the animation where to restart?  Looking at an article I found from @NealDavis's suggestion, [FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html), it shows something being _imported_ before implementing ActionScript code (just trying to exhaust all possibilities I can find).  I'm unsure if this would apply to my circumstance, but I'll follow any guidance I can get.

Comment: Yes. You are starting to see that coding in the timeline is not the only way and is quite arguably the wrong way. Try putting all your code in a separate .as file. More than that is beyond the scope of this post I think. Do a tutorial

Comment: I'll take your word for it being arguably wrong, but the only tutorial I could find relating to Animate CC used an ActionScript layer like I have here.  The program is so new that there is very little out there in the form of free tutorials.  I'm having to start over from the beginning because of an unknown issue we couldn't resolve, so I have much time before I need to implement the loop again.  As for the .as file, when I create it, how do I, for a lack of better words, "link" that to my animation project?

Comment: If you're working on AS3 and unable to find relevant tutorials, try searching for Flash AS3 tutorials. All of those would be valid in Animate CC as well, as its simply an extension to Flash. And there's no shortage of tutorials on Flash/AS3 afaik.

Comment: Ah, that should make searching for assistance much easier.  I keep seeing something for Animate Edge as well, is this also related?  There seemed to be an error somewhere deep within the original animation that is no longer present after replicating the animation.  It seems I ran into an interesting bug.  I appreciate you guys' help and suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your flicker may be a result of having an extra blank keyframe on one of your layers.

Assuming that you don't have any additional scripts to stop your animation (e.g. stop()), the Timeline should loop automatically whether your animation is inside a MovieClip or on the main Timeline. You shouldn't have to put any script on your timeline or in a separate AS file to make an animation loop. I would suggest this method.

Additionally, although you have the code specifying that you want it to go the first frame, it will ignore your call because the timeline is still playing and therefore the priority. One way you can combat this is by adding a stop(); function and a delay timer that contains your gotoAndPlay(0) function. This will take focus away from playing the Timeline and will allow you to execute your script. I wouldn't suggest this method because it seems a bit redundant.

However, if you're curious one way that you could approach this is shown below, simply add this script to the frame you want the animation to restart at.

```
//Stop the Timeline
stop();

//Create a delay timer for 5 miliseconds that is executed once
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5,1);

//Add an event listener that calls once the timer is complete
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerHandler);

//Start the timer
timer.start();

//Timer handler that is called once the delay timer is complete 
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent){

     //Go to and play the first frame
     gotoAndPlay(0);
}
```